# Why does managed-bean method invokes before filter invokation in post request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a filter which's used to set character-encoding filter.

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ua.com.winforce.online.site.http.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter itself:

```
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    FilterConfig config;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.config = filterConfig;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

A piece of markup user submit a form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink styleClass="ruski-button green-g full-width" action="#{supportController.save}"  >
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

The thing is the filter's method `doFilter` invokes before the `supportController.save` method when the post request comes. But I need to set character encoding before `supportController.save` invokation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Change the filter mapping

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

To

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> **SRV.11.2 Specification of Mappings**
>
> In the web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’    postfix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension    mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"    servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.